# Openpyxl - Copy contents from column A, edit, store results in column B

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a excel worksheet that has random numbers in Column A (approx 13 rows). I would like to add 100000 to each number and store that in Column B (same number of rows as column A). I am stuck on the loop portion as shown in the code below:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/d/Desktop/Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.rows:
    a = row[0].value
    b = a + 100000
    ws[row[1]] = b

wb.save('/Users/d/Desktop/Book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Why have you written `rows = ws.rows[0]`? That will return the return the first row.

Comment: it's just psedo code.. this logic is what I need help with

Comment: My answer is also just pseudo code but contains all the logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
for row in ws.rows:
    a, b = row[:2]
    b.value = a.value + 100000
```

Comment: This is the result I got when I ran your code      --------  a, b = row[:2]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: This is standard tuple unpacking… so your worksheet is only one column wide. You'll need to create "b" cells. Hint: `a.offset(…)`

Comment: I edited the code above. It's closer to the desired results, however, I now get a new error message. ws[row[1]] = b
IndexError: tuple index out of range